# Cannot simulate flutter app on emulator in android studio

Tags: android, flutter, simulator

I cannot run flutter app on emulator. Console msg showing "The screen cannot be set to the number of lines and columes" . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0dsG.png)

After waiting a few minute, console shows the msg attached in screenshot.. can anyone help me?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMzVo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Are you from Bangladesh? The govt has banned storage.googleapis.com endpoint here. Using a VPN will solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks bhai! I was stuck for two days... Using vpn solved the problem!

Comment: No problem. They have lifted the ban recently. Good luck